# Detecting mysql table lock from java

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I have a web application based on Java EE and MYSQL.

The problem which I am facing right now is, there is an event getting fired online, which is updating a table entry for a large number of rows.

There is also a batch job scheduled in the environment, say for every 6 minutes, which is also updating the same table entry, as mentioned above.

So the situation is that, when the online event is getting fired in the time range of the batch run, the table is getting locked.

So, experts please provide your ideas, on how to prevent the lock to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a design issue,take a look at using temporary tables.

Comment: But how to use temporary tables for updating actual tables